# Best way to add a "+" and "-"?

Tags: python, formatting

What is the best way to display either a + in front, for a float? Lets say if a user inputs the number "10". I want to have a "+" appear in front of it since it is a positive number. If it were a negative number then I would leave it as it is.

Would I have to use an if statement and then convert it to a string and then add in the + sign? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> format(10, '+f')
'+10.000000'
>>> format(-10, '+f')
'-10.000000'
>>> format(3.14159, '+.3f')
'+3.142'
```

See the [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) for the specific formatting options; prepending a number format with `+` makes it include a plus for positive numbers, `-` for negative. The last example formats the number to use 3 decimals, for example.

If you need to *remove* the negative sign, you'd have to do so explicitly using `.lstrip()`:

```
>>> format(10, '+f').lstrip('-')
'+10.000000'
>>> format(-10, '+f').lstrip('-')
'10.000000'
```

but that'd be quite confusing a specification to read, in my opinion. :-)

Comment: Holy cow I didn't even know about this

Answer (score 0):

Use formatting - and then remove any leading `-` from the result:

```
print format(10, '+').lstrip('-')
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I thought:

```
userInput=int(input("Enter number: "))
if userInput > 0:
    print ("+"+userInput)
else:
    pass
```

Formatting is just the way to go though, faster and cleaner.

Comment: `pass` is lowercase, no capital `P`; you *rarely* need to use it though. The whole `else:` suite can be dropped here.

Comment: @Martin Pieters oups! Typing on phone, typos happen thanks for the heads up. The else was just for "demonstration purposes"  :P

Comment: I sometimes wish the iOS auto-capitalisation function could be switched off too! :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters It can, can't it? Settings > General > Keyboard

Comment: @Haidro: I mean selectively while typing. :-)

Comment: I thought there was :P there should be settings accesible in yhe keyboard itself though.